# how to log the response data in grails

Tags: rest, grails, logging

Grails 2.5.  I need to log the request and the response to log file.

This is to log REST/JSON api calls. I need to log both the request JSON (which is easy with a filter), and the response JSON (Which is looking impossible)

an api call looks like this:

```
class myController {
   def myMethod() {
       def json = request.JSON
       :
       render(status:200, contentType:'application/json' {
           ['something': "something",'sometingElse' : 42]
   }
```

Tried creating a filter, e.g:

```
class LoggingFilters {
   def filters = {
      after = { Map model ->
      log.debug "${response.???"
      }
```

The question is, how do you get a handle on the output?  Tried respose.outputStream.toString() etc, but it says something has already got the output stream.

I saw one suggestion which said don't use render, return a model with a map with a single item: data, and render this outside against some dummy jsp.  Then you can get the model in the filter. The problem with this is that we have many hundreds of render statements, and we dont really want to retest everything (we have no automated testing).

Another other work around is to use tomcat request dumper [filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter), but this would not meet our requirements (e.g. we need to scrub certain output, such as passwords, want to be able to log to db, only want to log very specific things etc).

We tried this plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/httplogger , but it doesnt work with grails 2.5.

Comment: How about just overriding the render method?

Comment: I'm confident the OP doesn't want to give the response back to client-side as JSON... this is already done. The OP wants to _log_ the response. For debugging, analytics, or some such thing.